# Python - point class not returning correct points

Tags: python

So I have a point class where I declare a point and then perform operations on it. One of the operations is scale which takes in a point and scales it while raising an error if the point is not a float value. Here's what it looks like:

```
def scale(self, f):
    if not isinstance(f, float):
        raise Error("Parameter \"f\" illegal.")
    self.x0 = f * self.x
    self.y0 = f * self.y
```

And if I test it with this test code:

```
  print '*** scale'
# f illegal
try:
    p0 = Point(0.0, 0.0)
    p0.scale(1)
except Error as e:
    print 'caught:', e.message

# normal case
p0 = Point(2.0, 3.0)
p0.scale(2.3)
print p0
```

Then the output I get is:

```
*** scale
caught: Parameter "f" illegal.
2 3
```

But the output that I want is:

```
*** scale
caught: Parameter "f" illegal.
5 7
```

So the error message looks fine but the values that it's printing out are not. So why doesn't it print out the correct values? Here's my *init* and *str* methods:

```
def __init__(self, x, y):
        if not isinstance(x, float):
            raise Error("Parameter \"x\" illegal.")
        self.x = x
        if not isinstance(y, float):
            raise Error ("Parameter \"y\" illegal.")
        self.y = y

def __str__(self):
    return '%d %d' % (int(round(self.x)), int(round(self.y)))
```

Comment: I suppose `scale` is part of the `Point` class. One obvious error is use of `self.x0` and `self.y0` in `scale` method (which should have been `x` and `y`) because `__str__`  method uses `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning to *new attributes*:

```
self.x0 = f * self.x
self.y0 = f * self.y
```

`x0` and `y0` are different attributes from `x` and `y`. Thus, `x` and `y` remain unchanged.